# How to retrieve UDH from DeliverSM (logica smpp) and java

Tags: java, smpp

we use Java 1.6 and logica_smpp.1.3.7.jar

My issue is with concatenated messages. We always used the hasSarMsgRefNum method in the DeliverSM class to indicate that this is a multi message part.

However this was changed and we now receive GSM Short Message Service User Data as part of the DeliverSM.

I can get the esm_class of the DeliverSM that indicates to me this is a concatenated message part. I am having difficulty retrieving the actual User Data Header information that is in the beginning of the shortMessage field.

This is how I get the UDHI:

```
  byte udhi = (byte)Data.SM_UDH_GSM;

  if (del.getEsmClass() == udhi) {
      log.debug("This is a concatenated message part!");
  }
```

This is how I get the shortMessage:

```
  byte[] bytes = del.getShortMessage().getBytes();
```

However when I convert that to a String it looks like this:

```
  ^E^@^Cï¿½^B^This is part one of a test message...
```

I need to know how to convert that first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

I get the first 5 chars (header info).

```
  int char1 = del.getShortMessage().charAt(1);
  int char2 = del.getShortMessage().charAt(2);
```

etc..

The 3rd char is the message reference number.
The 4th char is the total parts.
The 5th char is the current part.

I hope this helps somebody in the future :)